# How to have xpath of with <i> tag

Tags: xpath

I have a html code like this

```
<div>
<a href="http://test" target="_blank">
<i>this is test </i>
"site for computer"
</a>
</div>
```

so how can I capture this link "This is a test site for computer" by xpath?

Comment: Do you mean to capture text `this is test </i> "site for computer"` or link mean href value `http://test`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find text of a then use:

```
//div/a
```

And if you want web address of @href then use:

```
//div/a/@href
```